# how is a colon (" : ") used in a method header in javascript?

Tags: typescript

I don't understand what the colon exactly does in the header of a method.

My guess would be, that you can declare they type of the parameters.

```
export default class App{
    private listeners;
    message(pattern: string | RegExp, ...listeners: Middleware<EventMiddleWareArgs<'message>>[]): void;
}
```

in this example, does it mean that 'pattern' and 'listeners' are created and passed as parameters of the method 'message' ?

Comment: That's not plain JavaScript; it's probably TypeScript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is [typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/), not javascript. Typescript is a superset of javascript which allows you to annotate your code with type information. The colon separates the variable from its type.

This type information is used at compile time to look for problems in the code. When building, the type information is all removed, leaving just javascript with no types.

Comment: thx. so in this case the variable/parameter 'pattern' is assigned with they type  'string' or 'RegExp' ?